# Подкорректировать тэг select

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подкорректировать, чтобы стандартный select,

```
<select style="border:0; width:200px; height:26px; font-size:12px;">
       <option value="n_1" selected="selected">All</option>
       <option value="n_2">X</option>
       <option value="n_3">Y</option>
       <option value="n_4">Z</option>
</select>
```

который выглядит так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
при активном All, был *чистым* :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е при выборе X-Z, чтобы они отображались, а при выборе All, - нет.
Спасибо.

Не пойму как подправить, чтобы заработала идея с цветом в Хроме и IE8+ :

```
<select id="s" style="border:0; background:#EEE2B1; width:200px; height:26px; font-size:12px;" onchange="fn()">
       <option value="n_1" selected="selected">All</option>
       <option value="n_2">X</option>
       <option value="n_3">Y</option>
       <option value="n_4">Z</option>
</select>

function fn() {
    if (document.getElementById("s").options[document.getElementById("s").selectedIndex].value == 'n_1') { 

       document.getElementById("s").options[document.getElementById("s").selectedIndex].style.color = '#EEE2B1';

    } else {


    }
}
```

Comment: просто убрать "All"?

Comment: @norbornen,наверное имелось ввиду что в выпадающем списке должно показываться _All_

Comment: не вариант, нужно сохранить информационность выбора

Comment: верно, в выпадающем нужно сохранить ...

Comment: что-то с помощью одного css не могу придумать, а с javscript все просто - если выбрано _all_ сделать цвет шрифта белым например, если нет - нет

Comment: ищете себе приключений на ровном месте. на `onchange` `select` повесить `if (selectedValue == 'n_1') { optionAll.text = '' } else { optionAll.text = 'All' }`

Comment: @norbornen, мне кажется этот код не совсем то делает, что надо

Comment: `option[value="n_1"]:checked { color: white }` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619406/css-selected-pseudo-class-similar-to-checked-but-for-for-select-elements

Comment: @norbornen - _option_ это элемент который как раз в списке выпадающем и показывается

Comment: @norbornen, подскажите, пожалуйста, как подправить мою ф-цию fn() в примере. у меня она 'скрывает цветом' в выпадающем списке, а нужно в 'шапке' ...

Comment: как-то так http://jsfiddle.net/7gscjg0j/ но это всё равно не даёт то, что ты хочешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За цвет выбранного элемента отвечает цвет заданный для элемента select. Поэтому его и надо менять, например выставляя необходимый класс

```js
function fn(select) {
  if (select.options[select.selectedIndex].value == 'n_1') {
    select.classList.add('all');
  } else {
    select.classList.remove('all');
  }
}
```

```css
option {
  color: black;
}
select.all {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<select id="s" style="border:0; width:200px; height:26px; font-size:12px;" class='all' onchange="fn(this)">
  <option value="n_1" selected="selected">All</option>
  <option value="n_2">X</option>
  <option value="n_3">Y</option>
  <option value="n_4">Z</option>
</select>
```

Comment: спасибо, помогли.